# Cannot read json file in java

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am using eclipse for reading a jsonfile. I put the jsonfile in my src->main->java->testjson->jsonfile.json . Now I am trying to read the jsonfile. But my progam cannot find the file. I get the output "nothing". Here is the code I already implement:

```
JsonParser parser = new JSONParser();
try{

Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("jsonfile.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");

}

catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("nothing");
}
```

Comment: Print out the stack trace of the exception instead of printing a useless "nothing" string in the catch block. `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: use the spring library  for parsing the Json

Comment: @Jesper , ur right. I get the message cannot find file. But the file is in the project

Comment: @LovaChittumuri where should I use it? in the maven respositories?

Comment: path to your `jsonfile.json` is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Your file within the project is called a "resource", which will be bundled in the resulting `jar`-file.

In `maven` projects such files resides in a special folder `resources` (like `src/main/resources/testjson/jsonfile.json`), in many other project types, these files are located directly beneath the `java` files.

Therefore you cannot read it with `FileReader`, because it will not be a regular file, but zipped inside the `jar` file.

All you have to do is to read the file with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testjson/jsonfile.json")`.

Your parser should be capable to read from an `InputStream` instead of a `Reader`.
If not, utilize an `InputStreamReader` with the correct encoding (JSON files should be UTF-8, but that depends...)

Code:

```
 try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testjson/jsonfile.json"); ) {
     Object obj = parser.parse(is); 
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println("failed to read: "+ex.getMessage());
 }
```

Code if parser does not support `InputStream`:

```
 try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testjson/jsonfile.json"); 
     Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"); ) {
     Object obj = parser.parse(rd); 
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println("failed to read: "+ex.getMessage());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're saying that you use Eclipse, i assume you also run your code via Eclipse.
As a default, the working directory when executing a Java program in Eclipse is the root folder of the project.
Therefore, I suggest to put your `jsonfile.json` in the root folder of your project instead of `src/main/...`.

Furthermore, you should not catch `Exception`. Catch more specific like `IOException`or `JSONException` and then print the exception message (`e.getMessage()`), then it is much easier to solve the problem.

Comment: @ but therefore I use my C:/home.. later I want to use the json on a testserver.. How should I now implement that? When I put the full path of my home folder it will not work on the server. how can I do that? thx

Comment: `FileReader` will look for the file relative to where you started your java program (actually the working directory of the process which executes the jar). So if you package your program as an executable jar and execute that on your server, the json file should be parallel to the jar file in case you still use `new FileReader("jsonfile.json")`.
However, for a more stable setup and deployment, i would recommend the approach from the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076422/6400698) and bundle the json file within your jar file and load it as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

The file "countries.geo.json" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.

You have to use the data folder as a source.

if Images not appear. Click on this links to see the images

[Right-Click on the data folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWOU8.png)

[You then see Buid path option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Sfx.png)

[Click on "Use as a source folder"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIyU5.png)

Comment: please try to give some deatils in answer (small explanation) if you are adding links of any images or any URL

Comment: I am new to answering query on stackoverflow. I had tried to add detail like basic steps like ->Right-Click on the data folder
-> You then see Buid path option
->Click on "Use as a source folder"

Answer (score -1):

Give the full path to the JSON file instead of the file name.

If the file path is home/src/main/java/testjson/jsonfile.json

```
String path = "home/src/main/java/testjson/jsonfile.json";
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path));
```

Comment: Later I will execute this on a nother test server. Therefore I need the path in the project right? I used ("/testjson/jsonfile.json") but its still not working :( "cannot find the file")

Comment: Can you try with the entire path rather than the relative path?